# SeekBar wont display current position, but still plays the music on the position the user wanted

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I recently posted a question that asks how `SeekBars` are operated. And someone directed me to this website/tutorial: http://android-mantra.blogspot.com/2013/09/seekbar-for-music-player.html

It really helped me alot and helped me understand how seekbars work, but I still have a problem. When I click the play button, the music will play, but when i seek the music, the seekbar will stay at position 0, although the music is runing on the position I wanted. Here is my code that i based (copy) from the tutorial.

```
package com.example.danbrianarenas.musictesterv2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable,View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Button startMedia;
    Button stopMedia;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        startMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stopMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        startMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        seekBar.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while (mp !=null && currentPosition<total)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e){
                return;
            }
            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        if(view.equals(startMedia)){
            if(mp == null){
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.filc2);
                seekBar.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                startMedia.setText("Play");
            }
            else{
                mp.start();
                startMedia.setText("Pause");
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                new Thread(this).start();
            }
        }
        if (view.equals(stopMedia) && mp!=null){
            if (mp.isPlaying() || mp.getDuration()>0){
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
                startMedia.setText("play");
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying() || mp!=null){
                if(fromUser)
                    mp.seekTo(progress);
            }else if (mp==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Media is not running!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("seek bar", "" + e);
            seekBar.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
        //TODO Auto-generated method sub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
        //TODO Auto-generated method sub
    }

}
```

PS: please tell me if you need the XML file. :) TIA

Answer (score 0):

As you are not chaning the position of seekbar on your seekbar change listener update your code and it will work:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying() || mp!=null){
                if(fromUser){
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress); // ************** you have to add this line
                    mp.seekTo(progress);
            }}else if (mp==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Media is not running!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("seek bar", "" + e);
            seekBar.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is changing the position, but still goes back to position 0 after 1 sec and goes back to the position wanted by the user. the seekbar does not update also. I get what you are saying and thanks for that. hmmm .... this bug is really annoying. haha!